# Oops! Your question couldn't be submitted because: It does not meet our quality standards

Tags: discussion

What's wrong with this question?

> What is the meaning of the term "cropped sensor"?

How is that question worse than this?

> What is the meaning of “cropped sensor”?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The question isn't necessarily worse; it's just triggered the low quality heuristic.

My guess is that it’s something like having ‘meaning’ and ‘the term’ in a short question triggering the heuristic.

The heuristic may also have been triggerd if you used that as the question title, because it would have resulted in the question body being the same as the question title, which again could be a flag for 'too simple' a question...

There are quite a few questions about the error on the main meta site, you might want to start with:
[What can I do when getting “It does not meet our quality standards”?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92074/what-can-i-do-when-getting-it-does-not-meet-our-quality-standards)

Neither question is particularly good and could have been improved if for example they included some context as to where you had seen the term used, possibly what your interpretation was, and why you were unclear if that interpretation was correct.

Comment: your answer was helpful, thanks.